# Loop through list of files and open them

Tags: vba, excel

The macro below requires the user to select which workbooks to loop through via a dialog box. I'd like to change it so to get the file paths from a worksheet so the user does not need to manually select via a dialog box.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
    "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
    "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
#End If

Sub ChDirNet(szPath As String)
    SetCurrentDirectoryA szPath
End Sub

Sub Basic_Example_2()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FName As Variant
    Dim FirstCell As String

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    ChDirNet "C:\Users\tshifflett\test"

   FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                                        MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(FName) Then

        'Add a new workbook with one sheet
        Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
        rnum = 1

        'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
        For Fnum = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FName(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets("Projections")
                    FirstCell = "A2"
                    Set sourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells))
                    'Test if the row of the last cell >= then the row of the FirstCell
                    If RDB_Last(1, .Cells) < .Range(FirstCell).Row Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = FName(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    ChDirNet SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

Comment: This question is overly broad and actually includes multiple sub-questions. Please narrow it down just to a single issue pertinent to your Title (i.e. "Loop Through List of Files and Open Them Via Macro"). Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Excel Workbooks file names (full path) are entered into Column 'A", the VBA solution in its simple form could be as following:

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim i As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim myBook As Workbook

count = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To count
    Set myBook = Workbooks.Open(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    'Do Processing myBook
Next
End Sub
```

You can further modify it pertinent to your business logic. Hope this may help.